# Can't specify exact date when retrieving Facebook request dates

Tags: javascript, facebook, date

https://m.facebook.com/friends/center/requests/outgoing/#friends_center_main
[image]

Hello, I am coding a chrome extension that will cancel friend requests sent on Facebook after a certain date. The problem is that Facebook writes the request dates in minutes, days, months, years etc. It is not possible to detect them perfectly on the plugin.

```
<abbr data-store="{&quot;time&quot;:1642405814,&quot;short&quot;:true,&quot;forceseconds&quot;:false}" data-sigil="timestamp" data-store-id="0">3 ay</abbr>
```

The dates are given as attributes in json format as below, but I could not find how to process this date.
{"time":1642405814,"short":true,"forceseconds":false}

```js
console.log(new Date(1642405814))
```

If I want to use new date directly as above, the year is 1970, but the request was sent a few months ago. It is outputting the wrong date.

```js
 console.log(new Date(Date.now() - new Date(1642405814)))
```

Although I converted it as above, it shows that it is 1 month, but 3 months have passed since the request. I can't figure out how to set this date. Can you please help?

Comment: Just add three zeros of a millisecond to the end of the time `console.log(new Date(1642405814000))`

Comment: It worked thank you very much. I couldn't solve it anyway. You have been of great help to me.

Comment: The vote button is not active for me. I can accept the answer if you can post it as a regular answer. You saved me from a huge burden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add three zeros of a millisecond to the end of the time

```js
console.log(new Date(1642405814000))
```